# have error when trying to work with VS2005 and SQL-server2008

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2005

i have C# program (in Visual studio 2005) and i try to connect and

work with sql-server 2008.

the connect is success but i get this error:

```
this server version is not supported. you must have Microsoft SQL server 2005 Beta 2 or later
```

what can i do ?

thank's in advance

Comment: It should work. How do you try to establish the connection? can you paste the code here?

Comment: Is it possible that you are using an incorrect connection string with wrong server providers in it? You must show us how you connect to the sql server first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There could be a problem if you are trying to connect to the database using design tools.
There is a fix patch available [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=E1109AEF-1AA2-408D-AA0F-9DF094F993BF&displaylang=en).